# Error uso de eloquent en relaciones de tablas

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

tengo dos tablas una es barcos y la otra es bonos, la tabla que contiene la clave ajena es bonos y esa clave ajena apunta a la tabla barcos, las relaciones están bien hechas ya que cuando accedo a phpmyadmin e intento crear un nuevo bono me sale la posibilidad de escoger los barcos existentes, hasta aqui todo bién.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema lo tengo al intentar crear una variable con la relación creada que no se por que me salta el error **"Property [barco] does not exist on this collection instance."**

**Controller**

```
 public function index()
{
    $bonos=Bono::all();

    $nombre_barco = $bonos->barco->nombre; //AQUÍ DA EL ERROR DE RELACIÓN

    return view('bonos.bonos',[

        'bonos'=>$bonos,

    ]);
}
```

**Model Bono**

```
   namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;


class Bono extends Model
{


  use HasFactory;

  protected $table = 'bonos';

  protected $fillable = [
     'barco_id', 'codigo', 'precio',
  ];

  public function barco() {
    
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Barco');
  }
}
```

**Model Barcos**

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Barco extends Model

{

   use HasFactory;

   protected $table = 'barcos';


   protected $fillable = [
      'nombre', 'titulo', 'tipo', 'descripcion','numero_personas','ciudad','puerto',
   ];

   public function imagenesBarco() {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ImagenBarco');
   }

   public function bonos() {
      return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Bono');
   }

}
```

Comment: El problema es que `Bono::all();` te va a devolver todos los bonos (en una colección). Y luego quieres hacer `$bonos->barco->nombre`, pero tienes todos los bonos ahí... ¿el nombre del barco de cuál bono quieres obtener?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El método `all` devuelve todos los resultados de tu tabla modelo, si quieres el valor `nombre`, tienes que iterar los resultados para que valla recorriendo de uno en uno e ir a `barco->nombre`

```
<?php

$bonos = Bono::all();

foreach ($bonos as $bono) {
    echo $bono->barco->nombre;
}
```

Ahora si quieres todos los resultados, puedes hacer uso del `with`, que te devolvera en forma de cadena `Bono->barco`

```
$bonos = Bono::with(['barco'])->get();
```

Referencia

- [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent)